# How to create/make your app LOCAL with Heroku/Virtualenv/Django?

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

Here's what i've done so far:

- Installed Git Bash and Heroku, and Foreman.
- Logged in, created a key, etc...
- Cloned a demo app from Git.
- Deployed/Tested it on the browser. It works.

I'm working on this directory:

```
*/python-getting-started (master)*


Which has this stuff:
Procfile
gettingstarted
manage.py
runtime.txt
README.md
**hello ( My app)**
requirements.txt
```

Well, by the files are named (**init**, manage.py, stuff like that...) i assume Django is hosted on the remote machine (Heroku Machine?)... And when it comes to running the app locally, i'm not sure how to use virtualenv to do that.....

Should i "set" virtualenv inside the remote folder? If that's correct, what's the point? I could just use python itself without need for virtualenv...

I'm not sure if my question is making any sense, if you need to know any other thing please...
Been trying to set up this for two days now...

Comment: It doesn't really make sense, no. Why would the fact that your files are called things like manage.py mean that the app is hosted remotely?

Comment: it's because these are the files that usually comes with the Django framework and because the Heroku setup i did was Django oriented.... The information is obscure for those who are unaware of Django and it's usage.

Answer (score 1):

A `git push heroku_remote_name local_branch_name:master` call will push that branch of code to Heroku. Heroku then does the following...

- Pulls in code changes
- Installs `pip` requirements listed in `requirements.txt`
- Relaunches the "dyno" web server by invoking `python manage.py runserver` on the remote web server.

---

If you want to run the web application locally, you will want to create a virtualenv and invoke `python manage.py runserver` locally.

If you are on linux, here are a bunch of commands that should have you working smartly. If you're not on linux, the steps should at least be illustrative of what you will want to do.

- `sudo apt-get install -y python-pip`
- `sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper`
- `sudo pip install autoenv`
- `cd path/to/project`
- `mkvirtualenv venv_name_here`
- `echo "source /home/your_username/.virtualenvs/venv_name_here/bin/activate" >> .env`
- `cd .`
- `python manage.py syncdb`
- `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: Thanks for answering this bro. I did some research and found out that these sort of work goes better when in Linux because of this weird problem concerning postgreSQL...Which i just installed and everything will be fine now. Thanks.