# Can't find .env file for locally starting Django app using 'heroku local'

Tags: django, heroku, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I want to local run my Django app with Heroku using, for example, 'heroku local -e .env.test' (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local). I am using virtualenvwrapper so my envs (test, dev) are not in my Django project server but located in my $WORKON_HOME directory. I don't know what to specify for the last part of the command because I can't find the .env files in the $WORKON_HOME.

I've tried `heroku local -e $WORKON_HOME/dev` and `heroku local -e $VIRTUAL_ENV` and get the same error:  `▸    EISDIR: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read`

Comment: You have to create `.env` yourself with your environment variables if you want any. Otherwise, don't track virtualenv, just add a `requirements.txt`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't follow that. Are you suggesting that I shouldn't use virtualenv?

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was that I had created a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io) directory called `.env`, conflicting with Heroku's `ENV` system which uses the same filename. Deleting the virtualenv and recreating it as `.venv` solved my problem:

```
deactivate
rm -rf .env
virtualenv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
```

NB. You can't just rename the `.env` directory without having to manually edit the virtualenv configuration too; better just to destroy and recreate.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion comes from what you think `.env` does: that is used by the Procfile (which is called by Foreman https://ddollar.github.io/foreman/ ) to set environment variables like:

```
A=b
C=d
```

`.env` there is *not* your virtualenv, which you should not git track.

Just use your virtualenv as usual before calling `heroku local` and track a `requirements.txt` (and possibly `runtime.txt` for the Python version, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python )

Heroku will automatically use virtualenv when you push.

As usual, look for minimal working examples to get started: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template

Comment: See my self-answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**Answering my own question:**
I was able to solve my issue by issuing the following command from the base directory of my Django project.

```
echo "source /home/your_username/.virtualenvs/venv_name_here/bin/activate" >> .env
```

[the command is referenced here: [How to create/make your app LOCAL with Heroku/Virtualenv/Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317355/how-to-create-make-your-app-local-with-heroku-virtualenv-django) ]

Reiterating, this was needed because virtualenvwrapper doesn't automatically create .env's. Thus,`heroku local`'s apparent need for a `.env` requires a manual creation of the environmental file.  @ciro-santilli-巴拿馬文件-六四事件-法轮功 if you know a better way, such as some option of `heroku local`, I'd like to know.